# Why plyr's join_all function causes r to crash?

Tags: r, plyr

I want to join multiple dataframes by using plyr's join_all function. My dataframes consist of three columns each, and they all have the same amount of rows. When I run the code, r is not able to finish its job; the whole computer lags and I have to restart it.

Here is the code that I've used:

```
library(plyr)

merge_corp_inv_count_noavg <- join_all(list(canada,china,france,germany,india,italy,japan,russia,saudiarabia,
                                      spain,turkey,unitedkingdom,unitedstates),
                                 by = c("date", "target_nation"), type='left')
```

I have used this code in the past and it has worked, although the dataframes included more columns then. Nonetheless it is still confusing that it doesn't work now.

Any ideas why it causes r to crash?

Here is a list of packages that I have loaded:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(tm)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(convertr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(zoo)
library(runner)
library(ggplot2)
```

Perhaps any of these clash with plyr's function join_all?

I am seriously afraid of running that code again as it wastes some 30 minutes of my time; so please provide answers if you're more or less certain. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If things were working earlier and suddenly crashed, it is better to check the datasets.  With join, there is a likelihood of some datasets having duplicates for the key columns and this could trigger a cartesian join instead of `left` join, and thus creates memory issues.

---

An option using `tidyverse` would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
list(canada, china, france, germany, india, italy, japan, russia, saudiarabia,
                                  spain, turkey, unitedkingdom, unitedstates) %>%
   reduce(left_join, by = c("date", "target_nation"))
```

Comment: Do I need any function before list?

Comment: @KenLee no, you don't need

Comment: Weird. This also caused r to hang. Functions like left_join, mutate, filter, etc. work though. Any ideas what could be happening here?

Comment: @KenLee I would never load `library(tidyverse)`  Try this on a fresh R session with only `library(dplyr);library(purrr)` loaded

Comment: try calling the package name before the function. Something like this: dplyr::select   Maybe your functions are getting tangled

Comment: Just to make this even more puzzling: the code works fine with some 5 dataframes; but when I've tried to include a bit more (7) --- it hanged again. Task manager shows that memory usage increases dramatically for r (95%). I've inspected the dataframes, but they look alright.

Comment: @KenLee how big are the datasets

Comment: Small. 3 cols and 6k rows each

Comment: @KenLee I suspect the issue is because of duplicates for those 'date', target_nation' in some of the new datasets and this creates a cartesian join which can blow up the memory

Comment: Can you check the counts of each of those dataset for those columns i.e. `list(canada, china, france, germany, india, italy, japan, russia, saudiarabia,
                                  spain, turkey, unitedkingdom, unitedstates) %>% map(~ count(.x, date, target_nation))`

Comment: I've just noticed that when I run your previous code for 5 dfs, the code is executed. But the join results in some 2 million rows. // Will do the counts as you asked, one sec.

Comment: @KenLee that is likely the problem 2 million rows is very big when your initial datasets were 6k in size

Comment: Oh, you're correct---the dataframes are identical. Will try to figure out why. Thanks! We can close the thread. How can I reward you?